# How do we create this algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a real number $A$ that represents the value $1-2s$.
Given a second real number that is either $B$ or $-B$ (its sign is unknown to us) and it represents the value $s(1-2s)$ or $-s(1-2s)$ depending on the sign of $B$.

where $s, 0 \leq s \leq .5$.

**Query:** Given the input $A$ and $(B$ or $-B)$ create a single equation that outputs:

- $s$ in case of $B$
- $-s$ in case of $-B$

The problem is easy as we can divide $B$ or $-B$ (whichever is given) by $A$ and get $s$ or $-s$ respectively. But the issue is the boundary case when $s=.5$ resulting in $A=0$. How do we tackle that boundary case?

The objective is to have a single self contained algebraic equation (without the if-else kind of logic or other tricks) that tackles all the cases. In essence the equation should be integratable.

Edit: In case $A=0$ we can have the equation that outputs a specific value of $s$ that makes $A$ 0 i.e. $s=.5$.

I am struggling with this for quiet a while, can someone please help?

Comment: Hint: $\pm B/(s(1-2s))=\pm 1$.  Can you write $s$ in terms of $A$?

Comment: thank you. but i am struggling to see the direction.

Comment: @MichaelBurr if i understand correctly, what you suggested is the following: $\pm B/(.5A(1-A))=\pm 1$. But in case of $A=0$, LHS is $0/0$ and isn't that undefined? what am i missing?

Comment: When $s=1/2$, both $A=0$ and $B=0$.  Also, $-B=0$.  So, it appears that the output is not unique in this case.

Comment: yes. but can we make use of the fact that if $A=0$ then $s=.5$ so the equation in this boundary case (when $A=0$) gives one specific output (whichever we choose, either .5 or -.5). In other works the equation stays linear?

Answer (score 1):

When $s=\frac{1}{2}$, $A=0$, $B=0$, and $-B=0$.  Therefore, the input $(A,B)=(0,0)$ and $(A,-B)=(0,0)$ is the same.  However, it seems that the output should be $\frac{1}{2}$ with an input $(A,B)$ and the output should be $-\frac{1}{2}$ with input $(A,-B)$.

Therefore, it appears that there are two outputs for the same input, and the desired function would not be well-defined.  Therefore, there is no function that can satisfy these conditions (let alone an algebraic one).

If you arbitrarily assign a value when $s=\frac{1}{2}$, then the resulting function is not continuous (it has a jump discontinuity), so, again, this cannot be an algebraic function.

Comment: in that case i am open to any function (not necessarily algebraic) that behaves as described above but in the boundary case outputs a unique output (say $s=.5$). The only thing is the function on the whole should be integratable

Comment: Integrable as a function of $s$ or as a function of the two inputs $(A,B)$?  A single point doesn't affect integrability.

Comment: see i am trying to construct a larger integrable function and this function (lets call it $f(A, B)$ is one of the terms. As I understand I can only integrate it if it has unique values (a long story), the terms $A, B$ are known at every input of the integration and I need to figure out $s$ or $-s$ using $f(A, B)$ or $f(A, -B)$ before I integrate the whole thing. And since $f()$ isn't clearly defined when $A=0$ I thing I can't integrate this whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain exactly what you’re looking for from the beginning.